# Check Processing - How does your organization do it?

Tags: payment, paylater, payment-method

There are quite a few checks that come into our office even though we have credit cards as an option. My question to other organizations would be "How do you handle a check once your organization receives it?" I am just looking for feedback on the best workflow with civicrm.

Currently my organization has an invoice that is generated and emailed to the person after they submit the contribution page with the pay later option. That person sends a check for the amount due with the invoice and then a staff member goes to that persons contact record and updates the pending payment to completed.

Additionally during the end of the fiscal year we have a lot of payments coming through so we use the import payments page and upload csv files to add payments to users records using their external id. This however creates a new payment and does not update the pending pay later check on that users record.

I would love to hear recommendations and feedback on how other organizations process checks? Is there an easier way?

Comment: if you exported your pending contributions then could you adjust your import sheet to use the contribution id and hence update the pending ones?

Comment: I agree with comment above - if you export them, include the ID for the transaction. Then you can update those transactions as opposed to creating new ones.

Answer (score 2):

On a day-to-day basis, you can save yourself a few clicks by using Contributions > Find Contributions. Also, instead of Editing the contribution and updating the status, you would be better off using "Record Payment" by clicking on the black arrow to the left of the contribution amount:

[image]

On a similar note, when you have multiple contributions to update, streamline the payment recording process by selecting the relevant records from your search and then using the "Update pending contribution status" action:

[image]

This action opens up a data entry screen that will allow you to enter the same payment details when using the "Record Payment".